Emission and absorption of photons by atoms in atomic spectrophotometry
My question is about the interaction of photons with the electrons of atoms.
In atomic absorption spectrophotometry the atoms' electrons absorb photons which make the outer electrons "jump" to a higher energy level and then that energy is "dissipated as heat". Whereas in emission techniques like ICP the atoms are exited thermally and then emit that energy as photons. I know that even in atomic absorption spectroscopy some light is emitted anyways and the probabilities of it do depend on the temperature. But my question is how is that energy dissipated as heat? I mean, what does the electrons energy has to do with heat? Infrared EM waves? Atoms bumping into each other? Or why thermal excitation excites electrons? I mean... Shouldn't a photon always be reemitted even if the electronic transitions could be in several steps? I just don't have a sharp picture of the dissipation of energy as heat.


Atoms bumping into each other?

Exactly this. The process is known as collisional de-excitation.
If an isolated atom absorbs a photon then the only way for the atom to lose that energy again is to emit another photon. However if the excited atom collides with another atom the energy can be converted into additional kinetic energy of the two atoms. And the kinetic energy of gas atoms is exactly what we mean by heat.

Thanks!!! Is the energy transfer to kinetic energy of particles the same happening in the ICP-OES torch??? Where the Argon remains ionised because of the energy of the magnetic field??

So why do atoms mainly emit in ICP-OES or flame emission???

@JonathanCellucci in ICP-OES and flames the vast majority of atoms collisionally de-excite and do not emit. The light you see comes from the tiny fraction of the atoms that manage to avoid a collision long enough to decay by photon emission. There are so many excited atoms that even a tiny fraction emitting photons is enough to generate an easily measurable amount of light.

Ok thank you so much!!! I don't know why but chemistry books (at least the one I'm using) never explicitly state how the interactions occurs.... This is why I prefer like studying Griffiths!!! Thanks professor I'm still an high school student in Italy but I really enjoy studying science and mathematics. Especially physics!!! Thank you so much!!!
